# Trying to NPM publish and install a custom angular2 component with Angular-CLI; only compiles the first time

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm having a most unusual and frustrating problem.

I have an Ng2 component called **via-date-picker** that I am trying to NPM publish so that it can be easily used in other projects. In order to do so, I have made it into an Angular2 component library. The via-date-picker exports a module called **ViaDatePickerModule**, which I want to import elsewhere.

In order to test and make sure that it is being published correctly, I am NPM-installing and importing it into an otherwise empty Angular-CLI project that I am calling **npm-test**.

So I run my npm-test application using "ng serve", and I get this error:

> ERROR in ViaDatePickerModule is not an NgModule
>   webpack: Failed to compile

Yet despite that error, the project compiles anyway:

[image: Has error, but compiles anyway]

And when I open up my project, lo and behold, everything works!!

But this only happens the *first* time that I run the project. On successive attempts to run the project via "ng serve", I get the same compilation error, but this time the project just flat-out refuses to complete it's compilation:

[image]

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, and why Angular-CLI will run my project sometimes but not others.

I've scoured the web for answers and tried every solution I can find for this error, as well as every other thing I can think of:

- I've tried adjusting the tsConfig settings in my component library
- I've tried using rollup.js instead of gulp.js to build my component library
- I've tried copying existing, working component libraries, then carefully swapping out the existing code for my own
- I've downgraded Angular CLI
- I've upgraded Angular CLI
- I've downgrade Typescript
- I've upgraded Typescript
- I've deleted and re-installed node_modules several times
- I've deleted and re-started my whole project twice

No matter what I do, I keep coming to the same webpack error that I posted above; that ViaDatePickerModule is not an NgModule. I'm completely out of ideas. Any help that anyone could provide would be crazy helpful.

For the sake of complete thoroughness, I've created a public [repo on github here](https://github.com/JMFrancia/stack_overflow_question) containing all the files involves, divided into two main directories:

- COMPONENT_BEFORE_PUBLISHING: contains the component library from which I am running "npm publish"
- WHAT_IS_IMPORTED_INTO_NODE_MODULES: contains the resulting directory that is being imported into the node_modules directory of my npm-test project

Again, any help that anyone could provide would be extremely, extremely appreciated! Really, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: I've briefly looked at your repo. Looks fine at first glance Curious why  you are transpiling your "component library" into js?. You could just easily expose your library as a straight TS library, no transpiling needed. In the mean time, I will clone your repo and try.

Comment: Thank you @AhmedMusallam! You are a saint for trying to help me out with this and I really, really appreciate it. I transpiled into js just because every guide I looked up for component libraries seemed to imply that was the way to do it. I'm open to any solution, though - my goal is just to be able to NPM publish and install an angular2 component

Comment: here is the thing. If you are %100 sure that ALL of your consumers will import your components, modules ...etc from a TS project such as angular cli. You can publish your `TS` source. However, if your want your  library to also be consumed as a `JS` `es5` or `es6` module, then you should transpile. Also, have you tried using the angular compiler `ngc` instead of the typescript compiler `tsc`? `ngc` is a wrapper around `tsc`.maybe you should start there and while you're at it, look at this: https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad

Comment: @AhmedMusallam You're right! Instead of going through this messy transcompilation process, I'm going to make typescript and angular2 peer dependencies, and publish the .ts files as they are. Thank you so much for the idea! If you write out an answer I will mark it as correct so you can get those SO points you so deserve

Comment: you're very welcome. added an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are %100 sure that ALL of your consumers will import your components, modules ...etc from a `TS` project such as `angular-cli`. You can publish your `TS` source directly without transpiling. Ie. you'll be publishing static `.ts` files that can be imported in any project that will do the transpiling for you.

However, if your want your library to **also be consumed as a `JS` `es5` or `es6` module**, then you **should** transpile.

Also, you can try the angular compiler `ngc` instead of the typescript compiler `tsc`? `ngc` is a wrapper around `tsc`. You could start there, There are many library starters put there that can help you start an angular library and get it optimized for `AOT` compilation.